# go to different page on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to go to a different page than the current window.location.href of reload?

I'm trying to do it this way with a jQuery event handler on window, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(window).on('reload', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    window.location.href = currentURL.split('!')[0];
});
```

Comment: You have to use the unload event and check if the page has been loaded before. You can see more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400182/how-to-check-page-is-reloading-or-refreshing-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: If you trying to prevent double posting, then there's better ways to do it. If not, care to explain what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: There is no "reload" event.

Comment: do you have the information (url) on where to go at reload time?

Comment: @fejese No. I'm using the history api to manipulate the URL to pages that don't exist. So on reload, I want it to go to the initial page that does exist.

Comment: @epascarello oh. I thought there was. Why am I trying to do this? I'm using the history api to manipulate the URL to pages that don't exist. So on reload, I want it to go to the initial page that does exist.

Comment: You should not fake the existence of a URL. If you populate the history with an entry, then make sure that your application can load that page. Otherwise what's the point? In case you navigate elsewhere and hit browser back button you'll fail to load the page.

Comment: @wordSmith if the initial page does not exist, you would get a 404 (not found) error - are you planning on putting this code on your own 404 page?

Comment: @ochi Yes, I do get the 404 error. I could redirect from there! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original URL was of the form `<orig_url>?|<new_url>` you could do this on button click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click', function () {
        // Original assumption is the original URL was of the form <orig_url>?|<new_url>

        // faking our data here for this example
        var currentURL = window.location.href + '|http://www.google.com' ;

        console.log(currentURL );
        var urls = currentURL.split("|");
        console.log( urls[0] );
        console.log( urls[1] );
        $("head").append("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=" + urls[1] + "'>");
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this is too complicated. Here's why I'm trying to do this: I'm using the history api to manipulate the URL to pages that don't exist. So on reload, I want it to go to the initial page that does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.It will fixed the problem.

```
 $( window ).load(function() 
      {
          var your_url         = 'your_page.php'; 
          window.location.href = your_url;
      });
```

Comment: @putvande you use document ready or window load when you refresh your page.

Comment: So why if you disagree did you change your answer?

Comment: @putvande yes i change it after your first comment.

Answer (score -1):

since you are trying to control page load behaviour at client side you need to have some mechanism to prevent this information at browser. You can make use of cookie.

You may reuse below code.

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function DeleteCookie(name) {
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }



$(window).load(function () {
 //if IsRefresh cookie exists
 var IsRefresh = getCookie("IsRefresh");
 if (IsRefresh != null && IsRefresh != "") {
    //cookie exists then you refreshed this page(F5, reload button or right click and reload)
    DeleteCookie("IsRefresh");
    //Redirect to new URL
 }
 else {
    //cookie doesnt exists then you landed on this page for first time
    setCookie("IsRefresh", "true", 1);
 }
})
```