# How to detect if an user clicked on refresh button or F5 or Ctrl+F5?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

**Edit:** Is it a good thing to use?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {

};
```

In this function I should detect if user click refresh and if YES then do this: `$_POST['enter'] = NULL;`

Comment: have you looked at `onbeforeunload ` event

Comment: check out this link. It will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400182/how-to-check-page-is-reloading-or-refreshing-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: You may want to use the keyEvent in javascript. This can detect wich keybutton the user pressed.

Comment: @Deep I need to detect when user click on refresh, but there is another thing

Comment: @Ramanlfc Yes, but I haven't found a working code, could you suggest anything?

Comment: @C0dekid how to detect if user click on refresh button in browser's window?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for capturing the key event.
This code can help you.

```
$(document.body).on("keydown", this,
     function (event) { 
          if (event.keyCode == 116) { alert('F5 pressed!'); 
       } 
});
```

Comment: click event + click on refresh button in browser

Comment: when press charachter "t" this event occurred too